# Se pueden controlar 2 scrollbar con uno solo?

Tags: javascript

Se pueden controlar dos scrollbar con un solo, es decir si lo muevo a la derecha que se muevan al mismo tiempo???

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#myDIV {
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    overflow: auto;
    float:left;
}

#myDIV2 {
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    overflow: auto;
}

#content {
    height: 800px;
    width: 2000px;
    background-color: coral;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDIV" onscroll="myFunction()">
  <div id="content">Div 1........................</div>
</div>

<div id="myDIV2" onscroll="myFunction()">
  <div id="content">Div 2---------------------------</div>
</div>


<script>
function myFunction() {
    var elmnt = document.getElementById("myDIV");
    var elmnt2 = document.getElementById("myDIV2");
    var x = elmnt.scrollLeft;
    var y = elmnt.scrollTop;
    elmnt2.scrollLeft = x;
    elmnt2.scrollTop = y;
    
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Con scrollLeft puedes obtener cuando se ha movido a la derecha y asignarselo al div  que también deseas mover, con scrollTop es lo mismo pero hacia arriba.

Para más información https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_scrolltop.asp